# What size is the upper bearing on a 2013 Trek Speed Concept 7.0?

Tags: headset, bearings, trek

I'm looking to replace the upper head bearing in my 2013 Trek Speed Concept 7.0 but cannot find the item online. Any ideas of a FSA/Canecreek bearing to replace it?

Just to clarify, the diagram below shows the 2014 service manual that depicts an upper head bearing of W276442. I don't know if that's the same for the 2013.

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you have a Trek dealer nearby? They should be able to dig it out for you in a minute or two.

Comment: When I got the bottom replace the Trek mechanic simply said "get a 1inch FSA or Canecreek bearing" for the top (i.e. they didn't have the part nor could specifically reference it). Would something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/FSA-Bearing-ACB-1-1-Orbit/dp/B001GSOF7E/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1471216851&sr=8-1&keywords=acb+bearing) work?

Comment: That makes it sound like they were telling you to get a 1" IS integrated headset bearing, which is wrong. This site appears to be selling what you need: http://www.enduroforkseals.com/id366.html .

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from Carl an Engineer at Trek. Turns out it is:

http://forum.slowtwitch.com/gforum.cgi?post=6040711#p6040711

> that's the upper headset bearing PN for all SCs, 2010-present, with the external steerer (aka bayonet style) fork. it's a custom
>   bearing, so I'm not sure you'll find it anywhere other than through
>   your Trek dealer.
>
> 1st generation SC 7-series bikes (which technically were model years 2010-2013) that had a standard stem on a 1" aluminum fork
>   steerer used a 1" cane creek upper bearing, PN 428420 from your Trek
>   dealer.

I wanted to buy it online so I found it by the Cane Creek model #

http://forum.slowtwitch.com/forum/?post=4773430#p4773430

> The original SC7 upper headset bearing is a standard 1" threadless
>   headset bearing with 45deg chamfers...your Trek dealer can order PN
>   428420...Cane Creek PN is BAA0004K.

Ordered part BAA0004K from Amazon. That should do the trick.